# mariadb UNION select how to return two columns insted of one row?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have the following query in mariadb :

```
SELECT
MONTHNAME (itd.DateOfshippment) AS Month
-- COUNT(itm.Name) AS Operations
FROM ImportsMaster itm
INNER JOIN ImportsDetails itd on itm.ID  = itd.IDMSTR 
WHERE itd.Market IS NOT NULL 
AND itm.Trader LIKE "%TEXT%"
AND itd.DateOfshippment between '2020-08-29' and '2020-12-31'
GROUP BY MONTH(itd.DateOfshippment)
```

if I uncoment  the COUNT clause and comment the MONTHNAME clause each query returns
a relevant set of data such as for example:

Qa :

```
Month
Jan 
Feb
March
Apr
```

and Qb :

```
Operations
3
4
2
4
```

I have tried various ways to make the query return the two columns in
a single query  using UNION such as :

```
SELECT
    MONTHNAME (itd.DateOfshippment) AS Month
    -- COUNT(itm.Name) AS Operations
    FROM ImportsMaster itm
    INNER JOIN ImportsDetails itd on itm.ID  = itd.IDMSTR 
    WHERE itd.Market IS NOT NULL 
    AND itm.Trader LIKE "%TEXT%"
    AND itd.DateOfshippment between '2020-08-29' and '2020-12-31'
    GROUP BY MONTH(itd.DateOfshippment)
UNION SELECT
    -- MONTHNAME (itd.DateOfshippment) AS Month
    COUNT(itm.Name) AS Operations
    FROM ImportsMaster itm
    INNER JOIN ImportsDetails itd on itm.ID  = itd.IDMSTR 
    WHERE itd.Market IS NOT NULL 
    AND itm.Trader LIKE "%TEXT%"
    AND itd.DateOfshippment between '2020-08-29' and '2020-12-31'
    GROUP BY MONTH(itd.DateOfshippment)
```

Yet what I'm getting back is a single column result such as :

```
Month
Jan 
Feb
March
Apr 
3
4
2
4
```

Is there a way to get the result as two columns ? what am I doing wrong here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you're trying to use `UNION` for this. The other answers are helpful if that is necessary. Simply selecting both in the same query will give you the two columns.

```
SELECT
MONTHNAME (itd.DateOfshippment) AS Month
,COUNT(itm.Name) AS Operations
FROM ImportsMaster itm
INNER JOIN ImportsDetails itd on itm.ID  = itd.IDMSTR 
WHERE itd.Market IS NOT NULL 
AND itm.Trader LIKE "%TEXT%"
AND itd.DateOfshippment between '2020-08-29' and '2020-12-31'
GROUP BY MONTH(itd.DateOfshippment)
```

Comment: Wow  I had already tried the same but without adding the comma , such a silly error from me!  Men sometimes the obvious is so hard to see . Instead of reviewing the code I tried all sorts of stupid UNION CASE etc . Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You would select two columns:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME (itd.DateOfshippment) AS Month, NULL as Operations
FROM ImportsMaster itm JOIN
     ImportsDetails itd 
     ON itm.ID  = itd.IDMSTR 
WHERE itd.Market IS NOT NULL AND
      itm.Trader LIKE '%TEXT%' AND
      itd.DateOfshippment between '2020-08-29' and '2020-12-31'
GROUP BY MONTH(itd.DateOfshippment)
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL AS Month,
       COUNT(itm.Name) AS Operations
FROM ImportsMaster itm JOIN
     ImportsDetails itd 
     ON itm.ID = itd.IDMSTR 
WHERE itd.Market IS NOT NULL AND
      itm.Trader LIKE '%TEXT%' AND
      itd.DateOfshippment between '2020-08-29' and '2020-12-31'
GROUP BY MONTH(itd.DateOfshippment);
```

*Why* you would want to do this is baffling to me.

Comment: That was the second close to solution , the only trouble is it adds NULLS to each responding column. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`UNION ALL` will select all rows from first query, and add the rows from the second query to that result.

You could do it like this (or simply select both field, and do it in 1 query):

```
SELECT 
  query1.Month, 
  query2.Operations,
FROM (
  SELECT
    MONTHNAME (itd.DateOfshippment) AS Month,
    -- COUNT(itm.Name) AS Operations
    row_number() over (order by MONTH(itd.DateOfshippment)) as r
    FROM ImportsMaster itm
    INNER JOIN ImportsDetails itd on itm.ID  = itd.IDMSTR 
    WHERE itd.Market IS NOT NULL 
    AND itm.Trader LIKE "%TEXT%"
    AND itd.DateOfshippment between '2020-08-29' and '2020-12-31'
    GROUP BY MONTH(itd.DateOfshippment)
) query1
cross join (
    -- MONTHNAME (itd.DateOfshippment) AS Month
    COUNT(itm.Name) AS Operations,
    row_number() over (order by MONTH(itd.DateOfshippment)) as r
    FROM ImportsMaster itm
    INNER JOIN ImportsDetails itd on itm.ID  = itd.IDMSTR 
    WHERE itd.Market IS NOT NULL 
    AND itm.Trader LIKE "%TEXT%"
    AND itd.DateOfshippment between '2020-08-29' and '2020-12-31'
    GROUP BY MONTH(itd.DateOfshippment)
) query2
where query1.r = query2.r
```